# Convert string date to new format

Tags: php, date, datetime

How to convert a string, for instance

```
$datestring = '28.08.14 10.42';
```

To a new format like `date("YmdHis.u")`

Thank you

Comment: Accept my answer to let others know your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `date function`. There is no such format as what you have required but the what I think you want to achieve is this.

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/184639)

```
<?php

$datestring = '28.08.14 10.42';

$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s:u", strtotime($datestring));
echo $date; //outputs 2014-08-28 10:42:00:000000

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$datestring = '28.08.14 10.42';
echo date("YmdHis.u",strtotime($datestring));
```